# JCheckBox uncheck

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Well, im saving reports but I've been having some trbs with the JCheckBox..

What i want to do is: When i click **NO** button, need no to save the file & unchecked the JCheckbox.

Due to everytime I press or click JCheckbox button actives the JOptionPane.

```
 private boolean saveReport(){

    String msg =    "<html><center>¿Desea Guardar el Archivo<br></center>" +
                    "<center>en el <b>Ordenador</b>?</br></center></html>" ; 

    JLabel label = new JLabel(msg);  
    label.setFont(new Font("verdana", Font.PLAIN, 13));

  if(this.guardar_Reporte.isEnabled()){
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,label,"Guardar Archivo.",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);  

    return true;
  }

        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,label,"Guardar Archivo.",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)
                == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                exportReports();
                return true;

        }
        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,label,"Guardar Archivo.",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)
                == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
            this.guardar_Reporte.setSelected(false);
             return true;

        }

        return false;

  }
```

Comment: There is no JCheckBox in this code.

Comment: Checkbox is "guardar_Reporte"

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have some kind of `ActionListener` or `ChangeListerner` attached to the `JCheckBox`, when the event is triggered, by the `JCheckBox`, you should check to see if it is selected by using `JCheckBox#isSelected`, when it returns `true`, call your save method

Check out [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

Comment: could you please help me with the code?

Comment: `if (guardar_Reporte.isSelected()) saveReport();`